# Is there any way to pass any type into cython and get return wholly intact?

Tags: python, cython

I got a compute intensive task which does some filter job for many times.

Things like this:

```
# (a large dictionary with a length of about 1m , value could be any python type , keys are all strings.)
dictionary = {'a':1 , 'b':[] , ...} 

for i in range(1e6):
    Filtered(dictionary, 'b') # -> which is expected to return [] in this particular case.
```

And I would like to take advantage of cython. Got a problem here is if there's any way to convert this python sturcture into c style , if there're some kind of pointer that can points to any python object , so that I can simply get input and return stuff intact to simply solve this problem?

Expect something like this:

```
cdef filter(pydictionary , pystr):
    cdef map[void *] dictionary = pydictionary
    cdef string str = pystr

    # ... some filter stuff
    
    result = dictionary[str] 
    return result
```

Is that possible to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: You loose a lot of the `cython` performance potential if it has to handle with arbitrary Python objects.  It has to use object's own methods and reference instead of fast compiled c code.

Comment: If your task is big enough to overcome the multiprocessing overhead, how about using ```multiprocessing.Pool```?

Comment: This question seems to be "is there a magical data type that behaves exactly like a Python object but faster?". You might get a more useful answer if you clarified the trade-offs that you were prepared to accept. I suspect the answer would still be "no" though

Comment: Got it  , thanks for all your comments ,I'm looking for cython solution in the first place instead of python multiprocessing , but it seems that there's no way to simply accelerate with c.